# how to use grep and sed on adb logcat

Tags: bash, android, grep, sed, adb

I'm currently using `grep` in combination with `adb logcat` (android console api). Now I want to edit every line on the fly using `sed` in a pipe. However when using sed after grep the output becomes empty. Does anyone know why?
Also: adb logcat keeps on running with grep which might be part of the issue, however I don't know how to fix it

here is an example

```
$ adb logcat | grep "Average inference"
```

gives me

```
04-16 13:51:19.528  8065  8065 E tflite  : Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 38350.1, Init: 2158247, Inference: 70339.2Overall max resident set size = 65.7773 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 10.3201 MB  
04-16 13:51:19.528  8065  8065 E tflite  : Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 38350.1, Init: 2158247, Inference: 70339.2Overall max resident set size = 65.7773 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 10.3201 MB
```

Now I want to use this pipe to extract all numbers (after "Warmup")

```
sed -e 's/^.*Warmup//' -e 's/[^0-9.0-9]/ /g'
```

to get the following result

```
38350.1 2158247 70339.2 65.7773 0 10.3201
38350.1 2158247 70339.2 65.7773 0 10.3201
```

however

```
adb logcat | grep "Average inference" | sed -e 's/^.*Warmup//' -e 's/[^0-9.0-9]/ /g'
```

only gives me an empty output

**Update:**

In general adb logcat gives me many arbitrary outputs which I would need to suppress. So a typical ouput would look like

```
05-04 20:18:00.063  5670  6838 I LiveIconUtil: mIconDpi : 480 , mTargetIconDpi : 240
05-04 20:18:00.081  5670  6838 I AppIconSolution: load= live icon for com.sec.android.app.clockpackage, from overlay = false
05-04 20:18:00.082  5670  6838 I LauncherActivityInfo: Load live icon for com.sec.android.app.clockpackage
05-04 20:18:00.082  5670  6838 I LauncherActivityInfo: packageName: com.sec.android.app.clockpackage, useThemeIcon: false, height: 144, width: 144, density: 480
05-04 20:18:00.103  5670  5670 E libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
05-04 20:18:00.138  5270  5270 W GraphicUtils: getTextEmpty : skipped with null text
05-04 20:18:00.138  5270  5270 W GraphicUtils: setLinearGradientTextColor : skipped with null text
05-04 20:18:03.232  4462  4462 I SurfaceFlinger: SFWD update time=991188773612812
04-16 13:51:19.528  8065  8065 E tflite  : Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 38350.1, Init: 2158247, Inference: 70339.2Overall max resident set size = 65.7773 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 10.3201 MB  
04-16 13:51:19.528  8065  8065 E tflite  : Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 38350.1, Init: 2158247, Inference: 70339.2Overall max resident set size = 65.7773 MB, total malloc-ed size = 0 MB, in-use allocated/mmapped size = 10.3201 MB  
...
```

So I would still somehow need to `grep` the "Average inference" lines, only with using sed instead as suggested by @FritjofLarsson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do (no need for `grep`):

```
#!/bin/sh

adb logcat | sed -n '
/Average inference/ {
    s/.*Warmup: //
    s/[^0-9]\{2,\}/ /g
    # Optional: remove the trailing space.
    s/ $//
    p
}
'
```

`/Average inference/` will only match lines containing 'Average inference'.
`s/.*Warmup: //` makes `sed` discard anything before the first occurrence of 'Warmup: '.
`s/[^0-9]\{2,\}/ /g` will replace every two or more consecutive non-digit characters with a space. The decimal point will be preserved since it is surrounded by digits.
`s/ $//` will trim the trailing space introduced by `s/[^0-9]\{2,\}/ /g` when ' MB' was replaced in the end of the line.
`p` is used in combination with `-n` flag in order to make `sed` only output the modified lines.

Note: You may write the `sed` command in one line like this:
`sed -n '/Average inference/{s/.*Warmup: //;s/[^0-9]\{2,\}/ /g;s/ $//;p}'`

Comment: apparently this still outputs all logcat lines. Maybe I need to delete all "non matching lines" first? Sorry the minimal example above was too minimal. I'll update it.

Comment: Your minimal example was enough. It's my mistake, I forgot that sed (unlike awk) prints all input lines by default, unless -n is passed. I've updated my answer.